# SignalR kills IIS Express when returning a List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

We have a MongoDB-based trace system and a Web Trace Viewer (ASP.NET 4.0, c#, MVC 4). One of the options of this Trace Viewer is follow the tail. I've implemented it via javascript polling but thought I could use it to learn SignalR.

I've made a local copy, updated it to .NET 4.5 and installed SignalR via nuget(VS 2013). I've been following the guide at [Tutorial: Server Broadcast with SignalR 2](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20) and documentation from [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - Server (C#)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server). This  guide states that

> You can specify a return type and parameters, including complex types and arrays, as you would in any C# method. Any data that you receive in parameters or return to the caller is communicated between the client and the server by using JSON, and SignalR handles the binding of complex objects and arrays of objects automatically

and

> [when you call client methods from the Hub class] You can specify complex types and arrays for the parameters.

The TraceModel is a simple class with several public strings (as category, message, server) and a DateTime created. My core process is:

```
IEnumerable<TraceModel> traces = GetTracesTail();
if (traces.Any())
{
    BroadcastTracesTail(traces);
}


private void BroadcastTracesTail(IEnumerable<TraceModel> tail) {
    connectedClients.All.updateTail(tail);
}
```

and it fails (and forces the IIS Express server to shut down) when it has to return an IEnumerable (I've tried also returning a List but it still fails). It will NOT fail in the following case:

```
private void BroadcastTracesTail(IEnumerable<TraceModel> tail) {
    connectedClients.All.updateTail(tail.Count());
}
```

So I assume it must be a problem with my JSON parser or my IIS express, but I don't know how to test nor fix it. Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Oh! and no, there's no exception thrown

Comment: What particular flavor of `IEnumerable` are you returning from `GetTracesTail()`?

Comment: GetTracesTail builds a List<TraceModel>

Comment: What happens when you try `connectedClients.All.updateTail(tail.ToArray());` ? At my office we have no issues returning `List<T>` via SignalR in IIS Express when running locally, but the times we do are usually in responses (not broadcasts) and when we do return them in broadcasts they're usually a property of a response object as opposed to the result itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was a problem with the json serializer and my short-sightedness: I didn't realize that my TraceModel had a Bson.ObjectId field (because it comes from MongoDB) which is not serializable. I've changed it to string and now it serializes beautifully.
Thanks to **welegan** for the comments.